# Error in Microsoft.CppCommon.targets MSB3073 exited with code 4

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to build a VS2013 project using VS2017. I solved many issues already, but I'm now stuck on the following error:

```
Error MSB3073
The command "regsvr32 /s /c "C:\workspace\myProject\.\Debug\myProject.dll" 
echo regsvr32 exec. time > ".\Debug\regsvr32.trg" 
:VCEnd" 
exited with code 4.
```

at C:\Program Files 
    (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
    Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  217

Any ideas?
Many thanks!

Comment: You must look in the Output window for the error message that Regsvr32 produced.

Answer (score 0):

This could a security problem  i had a similar issue, The VS was trying to copy a file into the systems folder, I had to run visual studio as a Administrator and that seemed to fixed my issue.

Comment: Thank you Wojtek. I've tried running as Administrator, but I got the same error